# Simple rewrite not working (.htaccess)

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to work out a bigger problem, which I believe lies in my `.htaccess` file.  So I stripped it down to the following for testing purposes:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^sandbox/htaccess/one.php$ sandbox/htaccess/two.php
```

I'm simply trying to get requests for

- http://example.com/sandbox/htaccess/one.php

to go to

- http://example.com/sandbox/htaccess/two.php

However, this is not working.  I simply see one.php.

I can confirm that `.htaccess` file is being read.

**What am I missing to get this simple example working?**

Comment: Is `htaccess2` a typo?

Comment: This rule would work with root htaccess.

Comment: oh, sorry yes htaccess2 was a typo :-)

Comment: @BizzyBob do let me know if my solution is working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, it will work

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^sandbox/htaccess/one\.php$ /sandbox/htaccess/two.php? [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, but I'm still getting the same result when I visit `one.php`, it does not load the `two.php` page.  Just in case my browser may be caching a redirect from prior tests, I renamed the 'htaccess' folder to 'hta', but still the same results.

Comment: I have changed the code a bit, kindly use this in your root folder, rename your current .htaccess to .htaccess.bak and use this code in a new .htacess file in root folder.

Comment: woo hoo..! yes, this is working now.  So my question is why doesn't the `.htaccess` file belong in the `sandbox` directory?  It works in the root directory

Comment: altering "RewriteBase /sandbox/" may do the trick,  I hope this solution have solved your problem, kindly accept this answer. :-)

Comment: I will give it a try. Thank you for your help on this.